# Why is CRTP not working in the following function?

Tags: c++, crtp

I am learning CRTP C++ pattern

My code

```
template<class Type>
class BaseOrder {
public:
    void sendOrder() {static_cast<Type*>(this)->send();}
    void send() { cout << "Send Base" << endl;}
};

class DerivedOrder1 : public BaseOrder<DerivedOrder1> {
public:
    void send() { cout << "Send DerivedOrder1" << endl;}
};

class DerivedOrder2 : public BaseOrder<DerivedOrder2> {
public:
    void send() { cout << "Send DerivedOrder2" << endl;}
};

template<class T>
void handleOrder(BaseOrder<T> order) {
    order.send();
}

int main() {
    BaseOrder<DerivedOrder1> obj1;
    handleOrder(obj1); // Send Base

    BaseOrder<DerivedOrder2> obj2;
    handleOrder(obj2); // Send Base
}
```

I see output:

```
Send Base
Send Base
```

But I expect

```
Send DerivedOrder1
Send DerivedOrder2
```

How to fix my code? Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you mean `order.sendOrder()`?

Comment: The BaseObject doesn't inherit from anything, so the static_cast on line 4 is illegal.   Beyond that, nothing matters.  You probably mean to be passing in a DerivedOrder object, but you're not.   The object is a BaseOrder object and only a BaseOrder object - and it doesn't inherit from antyinng.  You're creating the wrong objects in your main.

Comment: @xaxxon, you can downcast with a `static_cast`, there's nothing wrong about it. The code would be correct if, as you stated, OP passed a `DerivedOrder` object and also calls `sendOrder` instead of `send`.

Comment: @xaxxon - The whole point of this trick is that any `BaseOrder<X>` is, in fact, created as a part of `X` and thus every pointer to `BaseOrder<X>` can be cast to a pointer to `X`. But, obviously, if you do that you cannot create `BaseOrder` objects directly the way OP does (one way to guarantee that would be making its constructors `protected`).

Comment: By your description it feels you wanted to call order.sendOrder() in handleOrder (not order.send()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code:

`send` is not `virtual`, you probably want to call `sendOrder` instead.
and you should pass that argument by reference to avoid slicing which would make the call to `sendOrder` UB as the cast would be invalid:

```
template <class T>
void handleOrder(BaseOrder<T>& order) {
    order.sendOrder();
}
```

in main, you don't create the derived class, it should be

```
DerivedOrder1 obj1;
handleOrder(obj1); // Send Base

DerivedOrder2 obj2;
handleOrder(obj2); // Send Base
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fGj7aW9cf)

An improvement to avoid those mistakes would be to make some methods `protected`:

```
template<class Type>
class BaseOrder {
protected:
    BaseOrder() = default;
    BaseOrder(const BaseOrder&) = default;
    BaseOrder& operator=(const BaseOrder&) = default;
public:
// ..
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v3KK57vcn)